# Adding image as variable in Hexo (ejs template)

Tags: css, node.js, ejs, ghost, hexo

In my .md file I specified `blogpost-image` as a new front-end variable. In my `article.ejs` file I have following:
`<div class="blogpost-image"><span><img src=""></span><%- post.blogpost-image %><div></div></div>`

And in my .md file I have this path ...  `blogpost-image: /images/test.jpg`

How to make it work with images in Hexo?

When I do the same with a text value, such as `author: John Doe` it works perfectly.

Comment: Wouldn't you need it in the `<img>` tag like `<img src="<%- post.blogpost-image %>">`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge - did not work... for some reason, it does not "grab" the image, I see nothing front-end